# What is the point of stateless LSTM to exists?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

The main purpose of the LSTM is to utilize its memory property. Based on that what is the point of a stateless LSTM to exist? Don’t we “convert” it into a simple NN by doing that?

In other words.. Does the stateless use of LSTM aim to model the sequences (window) in the input data  - if we apply **shuffle = False** in the fit layer in keras - (eg. for a window of 10 time steps capture any pattern between 10-character words)? If yes why don’t we convert the initial input data to match the form of the sequencers under inspection and then use a plain NN?

If we choose to have **shuffle = True** then we are losing any information that could be found in our data (e.g. time series data - sequences), don't we? In that case I would expect in to behave similarly to a plain NN and get the same results between the two by setting the same random seed.

Am I missing something in my thinking?

Thanks!

Comment: This may be a question for stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44789322/5838180

Answer (score 0):

Data for keras LSTM models is always in the form of `(batch_size, n_steps, n_features)`. When you use `shuffle=True`, you are going to shuffle on the `batch_size` argument, thereby retaining the natural order of the sequence that is `n_steps` long.

In cases that each of your `batch_size` number of sequences are unrelated to each other, it would be natural to use a stateless model. Each array still contains order (a time-series), but does not depend on the others in your batch.

Comment: Let's say that my dataset has 100 samples and that the batch size is 10. When I do shuffle = True then keras first selects randomly the samples (now the 100 samples have a different order) and on the new order it will start creating the batches: batch 1: 1-10, batch 2: 11-20 etc. Isn't it how the shuffle works?

Comment: Yes that is correct. My point is that the actual sequences of n_steps are independent time series of themselves that never get shuffled.